# Solicitud de correcciones para guardar datos de formulario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo usando Laravel y estoy trabajando con formularios, necesito ayuda para poder guardar los datos que traigo del formulario en la vista en la base de datos, he tratado de distintas maneras, pero aún sigue sin guardar los datos, dejo el código.

Este es del modelo para verificar los datos que contiene los campos de la tabla relacionada:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sistema extends Model
{
    //
   protected $fillable = ['promotor','fecha','nombre','telefono','fechan','profesion','estudios','cedula','correo','estado','direccion','tipo','cantidad','via_atencion','descripcion_p','accion_realizar','ayudat','estatus','registro_sigcas','observacion'];

}
```

Esta es la función del controlador al cual se envían los datos que verifica lo que se envía de la vista:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request,[ 'promotor'=>'required', 'fecha'=>'required', 'nombre'=>'required', 'telefono'=>'required', 'fechan'=>'required', 'profesion'=>'required', 'estudios'=>'required', 'cedula'=>'required', 'correo'=>'required', 'estado'=>'required', 'direccion'=>'required', 'tipo'=>'required', 'cantidad'=>'required', 'via_atencion'=>'required', 'decripcion_p'=>'required', 'accion_realizar'=>'required', 'ayudat'=>'required', 'estatus'=>'required']);
        Sistema::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('sistema.index')->with('success','Registro creado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Y este es el formulario de la vista de cual se envían los datos:

```
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('sistema.store') }}"  role="form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <!-- Datos del Solicitante -->
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="promotor">Promotor</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="promotor" id="promotor">
                <option value="Jesus Rojas">Jesus Rojas</option>
                <option value="Daniel Martinez">Daniel Martinez</option>
                <option value="Maria Alexandra">Maria Alexandra</option>
              </select>
              <!-- Fecha de Atencion -->
              <label for="fecha">Fecha de Atención</label>
                    <div class='input-group date'>
                        <input type='text' name="fecha" id="fecha" required value="{{$now->format('d-m-Y')}}" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                <!-- Nombre y Apellido de Solicitante -->
                <label for="nombre">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido">
                <!-- Telefono de Solicitante -->
                <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Teléfono">
                <!-- Fecha de Nacimiento -->
                  <label for="fechan" class="control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                        <input type='text' name="fechan" id="fechan" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Profesion y Oficio del Solicitante -->
                <label for="profesion">Profesion u Oficio del Solicitante</label>
                <input type="text" name="profesion" id="profesion" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Profesion y Oficio">
                <!-- Grado de Instruccion del Solicitante -->
                <label for="estudios">Grado de Instruccion del Solicitante</label>
                <input type="text" name="estudios" id="estudios" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Grado de Instruccion">  
                <!-- Cedula del Solicitante -->
                <label for="cedula">Cédula del Solicitante</label>
                <input type="number" name="cedula" id="cedula" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Cedula">                
                <!-- Correo del Solicitante -->
                <label for="correo">Correo del Solicitante</label>
                <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Correo">
                 <!-- Estado de donde Viene -->
                <label for="estado">Estado de donde viene el Solicitante</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="estado" name="estado"  list = "id_estado" placeholder="Estado">               
                <datalist id="id_estado">
                  <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas</option>
                  <option value="Anzoátegui">Anzoátegui</option>
                  <option value="Apure">Apure</option>
                  <option value="Aragua">Aragua</option>
                  <option value="Barinas">Barinas</option>
                  <option value="Bolívar">Bolívar</option>
                  <option value="Carabobo">Carabobo</option>
                  <option value="Cojedes">Cojedes</option>
                  <option value="Delta Amacuro">Delta Amacuro</option>
                  <option value="Distrito Capital">Distrito Capital</option>
                  <option value="Falcón">Falcón</option>
                  <option value="Guárico">Guárico</option>
                  <option value="Lara">Lara</option>
                  <option value="Mérida">Mérida</option>
                  <option value="Miranda">Miranda</option>
                  <option value="Monagas">Monagas</option>
                  <option value="Nueva Esparta">Nueva Esparta</option>
                  <option value="Portuguesa">Portuguesa</option>
                  <option value="Sucre">Sucre</option>
                  <option value="Táchira">Táchira</option>
                  <option value="Trujillo">Trujillo</option>
                  <option value="La Guaira">La Guaira</option>
                  <option value="Yaracuy">Yaracuy</option>
                  <option value="Zulia">Zulia</option>
                </datalist>
                <!-- Direccion del Solicitante -->
                <label for="direccion">Dirección del Solicitante</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="direccion" id="direccion"></textarea>
                <!-- Tipo de Caso Solicitado -->
              <label for="tipo">Tipo de Caso</label>
              <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control">
                <option value="Salud">Salud</option>
                <option value="Denuncia">Denuncia</option>
                <option value="Orientacion">Orientacion</option>
                <option value="Vivienda">Vivienda</option>
                <option value="Pension">Pension</option>              
              </select>
              <!-- Cantidad de Personas individual/Grupal/Consejo Comunal -->
              <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de Solicitantes</label>
              <select name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="form-control">
                <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
                <option value="Grupo">Grupo</option>
                <option value="Consejo Comunal/Comunidad Organizada">Consejo Comunal/Comunidad Organizada</option>
                <option value="Trabajador">Trabajador</option>             
              </select>
              <!-- Via de Atencion -->
              <label for="via_atencion">Via de Atencion</label>
              <select name="via_atencion" id="via_atencion" class="form-control">
                <option value="Telefonica">Telefonica</option>
                <option value="Personalizada">Personalizada</option>
                <option value="Correspondencia">Correspondencia</option>
                <option value="Correo">Correo</option>   
                <option value="Twitter value=""">Twitter</option>          
              </select>
              <!-- Descripción del Problema -->
              <label for="descripcion_p">Descripción del Problema</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="descripcion_p" id="descripcion_p"></textarea>
              <!-- Acción a Realizar -->
              <label for="accion_realizar">Acción Realizada</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="accion_realizar" id="accion_realizar"></textarea>  
              <!-- Ayuda Requerida -->
              <label for="ayudat">Ayuda Requerida</label>
              <select name="ayudat" id="ayudat" class="form-control">
                <option value="Medicamento">Medicamento</option>
                <option value="Examen Medico">Examen Medico</option>
                <option value="Articulacion Hosp">Articulacion Hosp</option>
                <option value="Ayuda Tecnica">Ayuda Tecnica</option>
                <option value="Lentes">Lentes</option>
                <option value="Escaneo CP">Escaneo CP</option>
                <option value="Insulina">Insulina</option>
                <option value="Quejas Y Reclamos">Quejas Y Reclamos</option>
              </select><br>
              <!-- Estatus del Caso <-->
              <label for="estatus">Estatus del Caso</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="estatus" id="estatus" checked>Seguimiento</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="estatus" id="estatus">Cerrado</label><br><br>
              <!-- Registro en SIGCAS -->
              <label for="registro_sigcas">Registro en SIGCAS</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="registro_sigcas" id="registro_sigcas"></textarea>  
              <!-- Observaciones -->
              <label for="observacion">Observación</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="observacion" id="observacion"></textarea>             
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
           <input type="submit"  value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
           <a href="{{ route('sistema.index') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >Atrás</a>
          </div> 
         </div>
      </form>
```

Necesito saber en qué parte coloqué o estoy relacionando mal, porque según lo que entiendo de Laravel, deberia funcionar de esta manera.

Comment: que es lo que no funciona? te da algún error?

Answer (score 1):

Parece correcto, pero haz estos cambios para que veas como reacciona:
en el action del form pon directa la ruta: /sistema.

En la parte que guardas haz lo siguiente:

```
        $messages = ['promotor.required' => 'Promotor es obligatorio',];
        $rules = ['promotor' => ['required']];
        $v = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);

        if($v->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v);
        }
        $sistema = new Sistema;
        $sistema->fill($request->all());
        $sistema->save();
```

Al inicio haz la importación de Validator:

```
use Validator;
```

Pero este enfoque que utilizas y que te pongo como mejora no es totalmente correcto, deberías classes Requests, en tu caso tendrías SistemaRequest y ese request inyectarlo en método de guardar, quedaría algo asi:

```
public function store(SistemaRequest $request)
```

Todas las validaciones vivirán en esa clase ahora, esto hace más claro el flujo y el código.

Te recuerdo que también en la carpeta resources/lang puedes meter un archivo general 'es' para que las validaciones las manejes en español y estén todas en solo lugar.

Te recomiendo la documentación de las validaciones y requests:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Como dato adicional, deberías incluir posibles mensajes de errores que te este generando la aplicación: en storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: gracias, al final tuve que solucionarlo de una manera un tanto extraña y es desactivando el NO NULL en la base de datos la cual cree con postgresql y luego de eso me dejo guardar

Comment: en la proxima para crear las migraciones y crear las tablas utiliza ->nullable()